# Pass variable along multiple .on events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, delegates

I have this code:

```
$(document).on({
    focus: function(){
        if ( $(this).val() == inputvalue ){
            $(this).val("");
        }
        $(this).css({"box-shadow":"inset 2px 2px 5px #c7bda8"});
    },
    blur: function(){
        if ( $(this).val() == "" ){
            $(this).val(inputvalue);
        }
        $(this).css({"box-shadow":"none"});
    }
}, "input[type='text']");
```

How do I pass along a variable ("inputvalue"), that contains the value of the input field that becomes focused?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: David > well, that's also my question :)

Comment: *That contains the value of the input field that becomes focused*... hmm, the `focus` event handler is called when the field is focused. Then inside the handler you can get the value with `$(this).val()`. Similarly, when `blur` is triggered, the field must have been focused before and you get the value with `$(this).val()`... I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you want `inputvalue` to be a single variable, or one per input?

Comment: @FelixKling I think the aim is to implement a placeholder for all of his text inputs. He needs to pass that value to the `focus` and `blur` callbacks to know whether or not he modifies the value when the event is triggered - I think that's what the question is asking how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining it on a higher scope, like:

```
var inputvalue = $('input').val();

$(document).on({
    focus: function(){
        if ( $(this).val() == inputvalue ){
            $(this).val("");
        }
        $(this).css({"box-shadow":"inset 2px 2px 5px #c7bda8"});
    },
    blur: function(){
        if ( $(this).val() == "" ){
            $(this).val(inputvalue);
        }
        $(this).css({"box-shadow":"none"});
    }
}, "input[type='text']");
```